# Delegate of tableView is null

Tags: iphone, ios

Do I have to release a a tableView after pressing a button. The tableView is made of three rows and one section. I put in the file header  and within method that implements the pressure of the button I wrote:

```
     -(void) pressedButton: (id) sender{
            self.tableView.delegate= self;
     }
```

calling the delegate returns null. What should I do?

Comment: What actually is the problem? Where does your problem occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the tableview set up correctly in interface builder? Check to see if the value of your tableview is not nil. If it is nil, there is your problem. Is the delegate something other than self prior to tapping this button? If not, you can set the delegate in IB. Also, you need to set the datasource of the tableview. The datasource is where you get the real meat of your tableview.

Comment: And i want to add some line to the jmstone answer. If you are creating your table view dynamically then are you calling <tableViewDelegate> and <tableViewDataSource> protocol ?

Comment: You don't HAVE to declare conformance to those protocols in the header. Doing that just gives you compiler assistance.

Comment: yeah i know but some people ignore the compiler assistance.

Comment: Absolutely. But not including those lines wouldn't cause the crash is all I'm saying.